# How come not-copying a numpy array changes the data attribute?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

As my MWE below shows, calling `np.array(a, copy=False)` on an existing array `a` returns something that behaves exactly as expected, *except* that the `.data` attributes seem to differ. How can this be?

```py
>>> a                               # My original array
array([2])
>>> b = np.array(a, copy=False)     # Not-a-copy of the original array
>>> b is a                          # The Python objects seem to be identical
True
>>> b.data is a.data                # But their .data attributes aren't??
False
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd757c8>
>>> b.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75888>
>>> b 
array([2])
>>> a
array([2])
>>> a[:] = 3                        # Changing a indeed also changes b
>>> a
array([3])
>>> b
array([3])
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd757c8>
>>> b.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75888>
```

**EDIT**

While playing around, I even found that the `.data` attribute changes while looking at it!

```py
>>> a.data is a.data        # a.data isn't equal to itself?!
False
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75948>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75888>  # A different value than a minute ago
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75948>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75888>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75948>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75888>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75948>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75888>
>>> a.data
<memory at 0x7f82ebd75948>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [33]: a = np.array([2])                                                                             
In [34]: b = np.array(a, copy=False)
```

A nice human-readable way of checking for shared data buffer is the `__array_interface__` dictionary.

```
In [36]: a.__array_interface__                                                                         
Out[36]: 
{'data': (69508768, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (1,),
 'version': 3}
In [37]: b.__array_interface__                                                                         
Out[37]: 
{'data': (69508768, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (1,),
 'version': 3}
```

`a.data` can be used to make a new array, but otherwise isn't very useful.  And even this use is too low-level for most purposes:

```
In [44]: c = np.ndarray(shape=(1,1), dtype=int, buffer=a.data)                                         
In [45]: c                                                                                             
Out[45]: array([[2]])
In [46]: c.__array_interface__                                                                         
Out[46]: 
{'data': (69508768, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (1, 1),
 'version': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type:

```
help(a.data)
```

You will see that it does not return exactly what you expect:

```
class memoryview(object)
 |  memoryview(object)
 |  
 |  Create a new memoryview object which references the given object.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
```

It creates a memoryview that **references** that object. If you want the memory address use `id`:

```
id(a) == id(b)
True
```

Note that:

```
id(a) is id(b)
False
```

Because `id(a)` returns an integer and id(b) too and their memory address **isn't** the same although their values are.

If you want hexadecimal memory:

```
hex(id(a))
```

Also, from NumPy doc: [numpy.ndarray.data](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html?highlight=data#numpy.ndarray.data) (I really don't know why this `.data` is useful but it exists)

Comment: I think you are misreading the documentation string. The documentation says that calling the memoryview class creates a new memoryview object. It doesn't say that accessing the data attribute of a numpy array will create a new memoryview object.

Comment: Not part of my original question, but the memory address I'm looking for is that of the underlying array, not of the python array objects. The `id` function doesn't work for this: `id(a.view(np.ndarray)) == id(a)` returns `False`.

Comment: That's true, haven't thought why it is changing every time but I guess this is because of the python buffer object returned, I will search more about it https://docs.python.org/3.0/c-api/buffer.html @Martin

Comment: You are using view wrong, it should be: id(a.view(type=np.ndarray)) == id(a)` which is `True`the way you wrote the **dtype** would be np.ndarray and thus would create another array https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html

Comment: `id(a) is not id(b)` because two distinct `int` objects are created. This has nothing to do with the underlying arrays.

Comment: That's what I said, "Because id(a) returns an integer and id(b) too and their memory address isn't the same although their values are."@a_guest

Comment: @BrunoMello And how is that related to the question at hand?