# What is the `data` attribute of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In my search of a test to check whether two numpy arrays use the same underlying memory, I stumbled across [the `data` attribute of an array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html). [It behaves really weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61102237) (`a.data is a.data` returns `False`), and the documentation says nothing but:

> Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data.

So what exactly is the `data` object of a numpy array and what is it used for?

Comment: Most `numpy` users don't use it (directly).

Answer (score 1):

The following discussion may be able to shed some more light on your question: [What is a Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315280/what-is-a-python-buffer-object-pointing-to-the-start-of-the-array-s-data)

Comment: thanks for finding that.  Saves me from rewriting my answer.